# Passing data with UISegmentedControl inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UITableView that has a UISegmentedControl in each cell.  When the value of the UISegmentedControl is changed, I want to change a value in a MYSQL database.  (It's a public/private switch)

I have this in my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
[cell.pubPrivSegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(switchValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

and then this is my method

```
-(void)switchValue:(id)sender
{
    UISegmentedControl *sc = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;
    NSString *status = [sc selectedSegmentIndex] ? @"Private" : @"Public";
    NSLog(@"status is %@", status);
    //call method to change value in database using indexPath.row of tapped UISC
}
```

My question is how to pass the indexPath.row value to the selector when the segmented controller is tapped.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add target in this way:

```
[cell.pubPrivSegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(switchValue:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

And implement method :

```
- (void)switchValue:(id)sender event:(id)event {


    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView: tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
}
```

Comment: OK.  I must be doing something else wrong.  I keep getting the error -[myTableViewController allTouches]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.  I know your code must be correct as I've now found several examples of this for buttons in table cells.  I'll keep trying...